# Same bucket hosting static files at 2 different projects at Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As titled

Is it possible to have 2 same buckets (hosting static HTML files and the bucket name is this.bucket.com) at 2 different projects (say testing and prod)?

And if this is possible, how can i make it so that, if the URL is a testing URL, it will go to the bucket at testing project, and if its a PRO URL, it will redirect to the bucket at prod project.

Comment: you mean buckets with the same name in 2 different projects?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to have 2 buckets of the same name, it must be globally unique. If the bucket name is already used somewhere else then you'll get an error message.

[image]

Comment: Yeah bucket with same name.. i thought GCP has a way to identify same bucket name by differentiating the project.

Comment: It doesn't. Bucket names are globally unique across all projects. So if you have www.test.com in project A, if you try to create www.test.com in project B then you'll get the message above.

Comment: For reference https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#considerations

Comment: Okay say if currently this.bucket.com is located at testing project now, no bucket of the same name in prod project yet. If i delete the bucket, and create new this.bucket.com under prod project, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Thanks! Another question is, if i wanna create same bucket on both testing and prod project, but with different bucket name (say like testing.bucket.com and prod.bucket.com), and i want testing.bucket.com to access some css files contained inside prod.bucket.com, is this possible? Bucket accessing files from another bucket i mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194578/discussion-between-christopher-and-fred-a).